# how to solve Kernel size error in Fashion_mnist cnn?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

"required key 'kernelSize' not in config" in .js fine.

```
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [28, 28, 1],kernelSize: 3,filters: 64,activation: 'relu'})); 
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: [2,2]}));
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize:3, filters: 32, activation: 'relu'}));   
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: [2,2]}));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({ units: 256, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({units: 10, activation: 'softmax'}));
```

Comment: For Conv2D, filters and kernel_size are required arguments, and you're missing them in your last two layers. If that's not the issue, you should clarify your question.

Comment: That was the issue I figured it out soon after I post this question. Thank You